# How to get all the variables of a groovy object or class?

Tags: groovy

To see list of methods in a class I can do this -

```
String.methods.each {println it}
```

How do I list all the variables of an instance or all the static variables of a class?

**Edit1:**

[image]

[image]

**Edit2:**

HoneyBadger.java

```
public class HoneyBadger {
    public int badassFactor;
    protected int emoFactor;
    private int sleepTime;
}
```

test.groovy -

```
HoneyBadger.metaClass.properties.each {println it.name }
```

Output -

```
class
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do:

```
String.metaClass.properties.each { println it.name }
```

An alternative (given your new example) would be:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

HoneyBadger.declaredFields
           .findAll { !it.synthetic }
           .each { println "${Modifier.toString( it.modifiers )} ${it.name} : ${it.type}" }
```

Comment: That gives me `[groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty@f7901e, groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty@116b487, groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty@1a6492c]` Not the variables of String class like `value`, `hash`.

Comment: I copy pasted it into a groovyConsole.

Comment: The web console? Are you looking at the result? Or the output? The result will be the properties as `each` returns the collection it's called on.  The output will be the names of the public properties

Comment: Okay I was looking at Result. But the output only lists three variables - `class`, `bytes`, and `empty`. These variables are not there in String class. Whereas `value` and `hash` variables are there but do not show. Please see my edit.

Comment: So you want to see the private variables?  It shows class, bytes and empty as those have getters following the bean specification

Comment: Yes. Please see my second edit. The approach doesn't seem to work for public variables either but only for exposed Java bean properties.

Comment: @KshitizSharma also, your question title is about getting the properties of a Groovy Object, but both your examples are Java Objects ;-)

Comment: You're right. After compilation both are same, so I didn't think it would make a difference.